# Powershell Script to check startup type of service

Tags: windows, powershell

I was wondering the best way to use an if/else statement to check the startup type of a service in Windows 10? For example, if a service has a manual startup type under services, I would like confirm that it has the manual startup type without having to manually check it under Services.

This is what I've tried:

function validate-services {

```
$servicelist =

@{

"Example Name of Service" = "Manual"
"Example Name of Service #2" = "Automatic"
}
foreach ($service in $servicelist.Keys)
{ 
            if(Get-Service -name [$service] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){

                write-host $service "is correct"

            }
            else
            {
                write-host $service "is not correct"                  
            }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate on `I would like confirm that it has the manual startup type without having to manually check it under Services`

Comment: what have you tried so far? what did not work as expected? please, post the code you have tried to use ...

Comment: ```(Get-Service -Name "winRM" | select -property starttype).StartType```

Comment: I went ahead and added above what I've tried.
@Lee_Dailey

Comment: I would like to run a script to automatically validate the startup type of a service (ex. make sure the Core Messaging service has a startup type of Automatic, otherwise throw an error message). I posted an example of the PowerShell above.
@TheGameiswar

Comment: @Joseph - thank you for adding that info. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Function that display if a given service
# is correct based in hash values
function validate-services {

    # Hash keys and values
    $servicelist =    
    @{    
        "RasMan"   = "Manual";
        "wmiApSrv" = "Automatic";
        "SamSs"    = "Automatic"    
    }

    # Iterates over keys
    foreach ($service in $servicelist.Keys){ 

        # Get the current StartType from current service
        $startType = (Get-Service -Name $service).StartType

        # Compares current starType 
        # with the value of the key
        # and shows result
        if ( $startType -eq $servicelist[$service] ){

            write-host $service "is correct"

        } else {

            write-host $service "is not correct"                  

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I do have one follow-up question... what would be a good way to account for this scenario... 

Checking if a service is set to the startup type 'Disabled' OR does not exist at all (either being okay and should return that the service is correct)

Comment: Disabled is the correct value. In the hash $servicelist you can add entries like "NetTcpActivator" = "Disabled";. In the hash remember to add ; at the end of the entries except after the last entry.

Comment: If I were to add "TestService" = "Disabled" to the hash, the script throws an error saying the service doesn't exist. I'm looking for some type of error handling maybe that can account for the service not existing and ideally return "TestService is correct" in this scenario.

Comment: Do you want that if a service does not exist it returns "correct"? It doesn't make sense, but you can do it by adding if ( -Not (Get-Service -Name $service) ) { write-host $service "is correct";continue} to the beginning of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

this gives you a `[bool]` result based on the combo of `Name` & `StartType`.

the function makes both parameters mandatory, gives each a position number, sets each type to `[string]`, and - for the `StartType` - defines a valid set of choices.

when run, it gets the service info, compares the actual start type with the desired type, and finally sends out a `$False/$True` as appropriate.

```
function Validate-ServiceStartType
    {
    <#
    Comment Based Help goes here
    #>
    Param (
        [Parameter (
            Mandatory,
            Position = 0
            )]
            [string]
            $Name,

        [Parameter (
            Mandatory,
            Position = 1
            )]
            [ValidateSet (
                'Boot',
                'System',
                'Automatic',
                'Manual',
                'Disabled'
                )]
            [string]
            $StartType
        )

    begin {}

    process
        {
        (Get-Service -Name $Name).StartType -eq $StartType
        }

    end {}

    } # end >>> function Validate-ServiceStartType
```

examples with output ...

```
Validate-ServiceStartType -Name spool* -StartType Boot
# False
Validate-ServiceStartType -Name spool* -StartType Automatic
# True

Validate-ServiceStartType -Name ZigZagPapers -StartType Manual
# False
# lots of red error text
```

if you want to suppress the error text, change the following line of code for the one after it ...

```
(Get-Service -Name $Name).StartType -eq $StartType
(Get-Service -Name $Name -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue').StartType -eq $StartType
```

i prefer to get the error and deal with it [perhaps with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`], but you may well prefer otherwise. [*grin*]